# How to send an email from the app in liveCode?

Tags: livecode

I'm trying to send an email from an app and I'm not succeeding!
Maybe someone can help me?
(I do not want the email sending button to lead to an application that sends the email like the REVMAIL command but LIVECODE will send the email)
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the tsNet library and query the smtp server manually as shown in this post https://lessons.livecode.com/m/4071/l/685661-how-to-send-e-mail-using-the-tsnet-external

Keep in mind that the tsNet library is not included in the Community Edition of Livecode, so if you are using this version, you will have to look to other libraries or maybe try to use CURL with the shell() function.

Comment: But I use the community version

Comment: @tcrvo Then you have two options:

Use an smtp library for livecode, i never used one but you can find it here https://github.com/trozware/rev_stacks. Note that it doesn't support TLS/SSL connection.

 For Windows and MacOS you could make a shell call to cUrl and use it to connect to an smtp server. Here you find information about sending emails with CURL https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/smtp.